# Printing a new line using awk

Tags: awk, grep

I have a load of files in which I need to take out specific rows and then put the data I've taken out into a spreadsheet. An example would be my file shows:

```
Name: w

Age: x

Height: y

Weight: z
```

I only want the age, height and weight, so I first ran:

```
grep -E 'Age|Height|Weight' [input file] > output.txt
```

Because of the number of files, my output now looks like

```
Age 1
 
Height 1

Weight 1

Age 2

Height 2

Weight 2

etc...
```

What I now want is to run an awk script so it goes through my new output.txt file and first finds every row with the word 'Age' and the prints it. Once it has done all the 'Age' ones, it then does the heigh and then weight. I ran the script:

```
awk -F"\t" '/Age/ {print} /Height/ {print}' output.txt >output2.txt
```

But if just prints it like the original out put file. How do I change it so after it has done all the Age ones, it then finds the height ones?

EDIT:

My desired output is for the file to be

> Age 1
>
> Age 2
>
> Height 1
>
> Height 2
>
> Weight 1
>
> Weight 2
>
> etc..

Just to clarify, the Age 1 is the row with 'age' in it from file 1, etc.

Comment: Why not run 3 separate scripts?

Comment: I want to try and do it all in one go because that was just the example. I have 12 words I'm looking for in 23 different folders, so 23 * 12 scripts will be annoying to run and I'm lazy

Comment: Why the title is print newline? I don't see it relates to your question.

Comment: is it fine if we suggest solution in python?

Comment: @harish.venkat I'm not sure what Python is...at my work we have unix and emacs (if that means anything). I don't even know how it works in general. I'm trying to learn as I go along as I'm new lol

Comment: You should have specified that fields must not be hardcoded in the script. Or else my solution is still valid.

Comment: @Gnouc Because I want a new line after each "section".

Answer (score 1):

awk only runs through the file once by default, running all the blocks in order, which is why it gives you the output you got. You can get the behaviour you want using [an array](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html) to save the lines as you go, while still only processing the file once:

```
BEGIN {
    AgeIndex = 1
    HeightIndex = 1
}
/Age/ {
    ages[AgeIndex] = $0
    AgeIndex+=1
}
/Height/ {
    heights[HeightIndex] = $0
    HeightIndex+=1
}
END {
    for (x = 1; x < AgeIndex; x++)
        print ages[x] "\n"
    for (x = 1; x < HeightIndex; x++)
        print heights[x] "\n"
}
```

Save that into, say, `filter.awk` and then run:

```
awk -f filter.awk output.txt > output2.txt
```

to get the output you want:

```
$ awk -f filter.awk < data
Age 1

Age 2

Height 1

Height 2
```

What we're doing is making two arrays `ages` and `heights` and saving each matching line into them as we go. `AgeIndex` holds how far through the array we're up to. At the end, we're printing out every line we saved (and an extra newline like you want), first all the ages, then all the heights.

The arrays will hold the entire file in memory by the end, so if your file is particularly large you have to trade off that memory usage for time in going through the whole file more than once. At this point it's essentially the same as a program in any other language - if you don't have any particular reason to use awk, you might prefer another language. To be honest, I think I'd recommend that - awk isn't buying you much here.

Answer (score 1):

With `gawk`:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '
    { a[$1]++ }
    END {
        n = asorti(a,b);
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            print b[i];
            if (i%2 == 0) {
                printf "\n";
            }
        }
    }
' output.txt
Age 1
Age 2

Height 1
Height 2

Weight 1
Weight 2
```

Comment: That didn't work, it just printed out Age and Height, the exact same way as before, but twice

Comment: @Kaish: Can you give us your wanted output?

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

`python` solution for this problem:

```
from collections import defaultdict
f = open("output.txt", "r")
d = defaultdict(list)
for line in f:
   line = line.strip()
   if line != '':
     arr = line.split(" ")
     d[arr[0]].append(arr[1])
print d.items()
```

I have hashed using first column and put it in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the blank lines are not part of your actual file, or that at least you don't care about them. If so, all you need is `sort`:

```
$ cat output.txt
Age 1
Height 1
Weight 1
Age 2
Height 2
Weight 2

$ sort output.txt
Age 1
Age 2
Height 1
Height 2
Weight 1
Weight 2
```

However, unless your files are too large to hold in memory, it might be simpler to do the whole thing in a single step:

```
grep -whE 'Age|Height|Weight' *txt | sort > outfile
```

The above will search for `Age` or `Height` or `Weight` in all files whose name ends in `txt` in the current directory (`*txt`). The `-w` means "match whole words only" (so that `Age` does not match `Ageing` for example), the `-h` is needed because without it, the name of the file is printed along with the matching line when more than one input file is given. The `-E` enables extended regular expressions which gives us `|` for OR.

**NOTE:**  If, for some reason, you do actually want the extra blank line between each entry (which is not what your `grep` command would produce), you can add it with:

```
grep -whE 'Age|Height|Weight' *txt | sort | sed 's/$/\n/'
```

---

#### Example

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do echo -e "Name $i\nAge $i\nHeight $i\nWeight $i" > $i.txt; done
$ for f in *txt; do echo " -- $f --"; cat $f; done
 -- 1.txt --
Name 1
Age 1
Height 1
Weight 1
 -- 2.txt --
Name 2
Age 2
Height 2
Weight 2
 -- 3.txt --
Name 3
Age 3
Height 3
Weight 3

$ grep -whE 'Age|Height|Weight' *txt | sort
Age 1
Age 2
Age 3
Height 1
Height 2
Height 3
Weight 1
Weight 2
Weight 3
```

---

In any case, even if `sort` won't cut it for you, I would do this kind of thing in Perl, not `awk` (this is assuming you want the extra blank lines which,again, you probably don't):

```
$ perl -ane '$k{$F[0]}.=$_."\n" if /./; 
    END{print $k{$_},"\n" for sort keys (%k)}' output.txt 
Age 1

Age 2


Height 1

Height 2


Weight 1

Weight 2
```

You can pass that through `head -n -2` to get rid of the final two blank lines if you don't want them.

Comment: @teron: The OP want put a newline at the end of each segment.

Comment: @Gnouc I think they probably don't actually. The output of the `grep` in the OP would not produce those lines so I am assuming they don't exist in the actual file. In any case, they're easy enough to add, see update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort`:

```
grep -E 'Age|Height|Weight' [input file] | sort > output.txt
```